# sorting a vector on its element's feature

Tags: c++

First, I would like to thank people for having helped me so far. You are great!!!!! (if only you knew it)

```
typedef template<class T>struct 
{
   T homepet_;
   T wildpet_;
}Animal;

std::vector<Animal> va;
std::sort(va.begin(),va.end(),Pred<std::string>(sort_based_on_bool_and_arg));
```

I would like Pred(sort_based_on_bool_and_arg) used to sort vector based on
1. if user inputs true it is ascending or descending otherwise
2. if user inputs choose homepet_ as argument then it sorts for homepet_ or it will sort wildpet_

Comment: `va` is a type, not an object.

Comment: For those who wonder at Nawaz's comment, it's been fixed in the question afterwards.

Comment: If the user inputs true where? Where does the user choose anything?

Comment: The syntax declaring `Animal` is glaringly wrong. In C++, correct syntax to declare a struct is `struct Animal { ... }`, **not** `typedef struct { ... } Animal`. While both will work for plain struct (to keep compatibility with C), the later won't work for templates, since typedef can't define templates, only concrete types.

Comment: Nawaz, I am sorry, it's unintentional. I just reacted awkwardly right after I saw your pointer. Thank you and everyone for your posts.

Comment: @Jan and @Dalton: Even now there is a problem. `Animal` is a typedef of a class template, which is illegal. Typedef of templates is not allowed.

Comment: Thank you, Tony's answer is the final answer ($$$$$$$) :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need something along these lines:

```
struct functor
{
    inline bool operator()(const Animal& a, const Animal& b) const
    {
        return (does a come before b);
    }
};

typedef std::vector<Animal> va;
va list;
std::sort(list.begin(), list.end(), functor()); //call operator() on functor
```

Comment: The operator has to have 2 animals (const references preferably) as arguments. The `Pred<....>` makes no sense there (`functor` is predicate).

Comment: @Tony the Tiger : It's appropriate that you help sorting out yourself =)

Comment: @Dalton: The problem is that you didn't really state the requirements. You didn't describe what you think the `sort_based_on_bool_and_arg` is, so I couldn't refer to it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what `Pred` is supposed to be, but I do know it shouldn't be there.

`sort` takes a binary predicate on 2 (references to) members of the vector implementing strict weak ordering. A binary predicate can be either a function or an object with `operator()`. If you can compare two `Animal` objects, just create a function:

```
bool animal_less_than(const Animal &l, const Animal &r) { ... }
```

and call sort like:

```
std::sort(list.begin(), list.end(), &animal_less_than);
```

If you need some extra parameter, you'll need:

```
struct animal_less_than {
    type_of_extra_data extra_data;
    animal_less_than(type_of_extra_data extra_data) : extra_data(extra_data) {}
    bool operator()(const Animal &l, const Animal &r) { ... }
};
```

and call sort like:

```
std::sort(list.begin(), list.end(), animal_less_than(extra_data));
```

On a side note, the syntax declaring Animal is wrong. It should be:

```
template <typename T>
struct Animal {
    T homepet_;
    T wildpet_;
};
```

and for the matter, it should probably be a `class` rather than `struct` and should be encapsulated.